# Insert data in multiple tables at a time with repeated values

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, common-table-expression, postgresql-9.2

I have to insert data into first and second table directly. But the third table which I received data as array and inserted into 3rd table as same.

In my 3rd table values will be repeated. Ex:

values:

```
{name=ff,age=45,empid=23,desig=se,offid=1,details=kk,offid=2,details=aa,offid=3,details=bb,offid=4,details=cc}
```

So using 2nd table `userid` as same for all the `offid`, but details and other columns are different

**@My issue is i will get single hit but i need to iterate for 3rd table.**

```
with first_insert as (
   insert into sample(name,age)
   values(?,?)
   RETURNING id
   ),
second_insert as (
   insert into sample1(empid,desig)
   values((select id from first_insert),?)
   RETURNING userid
   )
insert into sample2(offid,details)
values((select userid from second_insert),?)
```

Is this available or possible in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely possible.
You can join rows from CTEs to `VALUES` expressions to combine them for a new `INSERT` in a [data-modifying CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING). Something like this:

```
WITH first_insert AS (
   INSERT INTO sample(name,age)
   VALUES (?,?)
   RETURNING id
   )
 , second_insert AS (
   INSERT INTO sample1(empid, desig, colx)
   SELECT i1.id, v.desig, v.colx
   FROM   first_insert i1
       , (VALUES(?,?)) AS v(desig, colx)
   RETURNING userid
   )
INSERT INTO sample2(offid, details, col2, ...)
SELECT i2.userid, v.details, ...
FROM   second_insert i2
    , (VALUES (?,?, ...)) AS v(details, col2, ...);
```